# Laravel: Recommended way to populate different parts of a blade template using multiple controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In a blade template, I have this

1. `@section('x')`
2. `@section('y')`

I want to have different controllers populate these sections. Is this the best way to approach this or should I do this:

1. create controller `xy`
2. `xy` calls methods from contoller `x` and `y`
3. merges the data into an array and returns the blade template view with the array.

Both controllers call their respective SQL queries.
`@section('x')` appears on multiple pages though `section('y')` is unique in each of it's respective page.

Or, is there a much better alternative?

Comment: Is the template like an app layout? Or just a single view file?

Comment: single view file.

Comment: Why is it some important both controllers have a section in the same view file? Why not create separate view files for each controller?

Comment: Have a look at using a single controller, this controller could use two (or more) Repositories for its data. This is a (somewhat older) tutorial, but should give you a general impression on what todo: https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/